# How to remove multi-level menu item with children in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have unlimited level menu structure in MySQL, where parent and children elements are connected with column `p_id`:

```
+----+------+------+----------------+
| id | p_id | sort | name_en        |
+----+------+------+----------------+
|  1 |    0 |    1 | menu-1         |
|  2 |    0 |    2 | menu-2         |
|  3 |    0 |    6 | menu-3         |
|  4 |    2 |    3 | sub-menu-2-1   |
|  5 |    2 |    4 | sub-menu-2-2   |
|  6 |    5 |    5 | sub-menu-2-2-1 |
+----+------+------+----------------|
```

What is best practice for deleting root menu element with sub-menu elements?

I can achieve it with PHP recursion,  but it will cause some number of queries.

So I need to find out if is there any possible way to do it with one MySQL query.

Comment: Convert the structure of the table to a [nested set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model), so you can do operations on them easily in SQL.

Comment: It will change all my methods which I already have with menu. :(  Any other ideas?

Comment: In my opinion your database has a bad structure for this kind of thing, how is the `p_id` matched? From the `name_en` field? For example `menu-2` has rows with id 4 and 5 has children? If so you should have a column that identifies the parent univocally by id, then it would be easy to see the menu structure.

Comment: no, `name_en` is just a `varchar(255)` name. It can be changed. `p_id` is just `id` of parent element and when I need to get tree structure of menu, I use `php reference` with single while loop without recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have `name_en`, cannot you use that one to delete the rows? For example,

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `id` = 2 OR `name_en` LIKE 'sub-menu-2-%'
```

---

**New method:**

You can use a [Foreign Key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) with a constraint. I created your table and called it treelist,

```
CREATE TABLE  `treelist` (
  `item_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `name_en` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`item_id`),
  KEY `FK_parent_id` (`parent_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_parent_id` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `treelist` (`item_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I then added some test data, the ones you had in your question,

```
INSERT INTO `treelist` (`item_id`, `parent_id`, `name_en`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, 'Menu 1'), (NULL, NULL, 'Menu 2'), (NULL, NULL, 'Menu 3'), (NULL, 2, 'Sub Menu 2-1'), (NULL, 2, 'Sub Menu 2-2'), (NULL, 5, 'Sub Menu 2-2-1');
```

Now, when you delete a row, for example

```
DELETE FROM `treelist` WHERE `item_id` = 2
```

It will delete all children, grand-children etc as well. Afterwards the table looks like,

```
+----+------+----------------+ 
| id | p_id | name_en        |
+----+------+----------------+ 
|  1 | NULL | Menu 1         | 
|  3 | NULL | Menu 3         |
+----+------+----------------+
```

Comment: no, `name_en` is just name of the menu item. it can be change to any string.

Comment: What a shame! :P What MySQL version are you using?

Comment: I use `MySQL 5.5.37`, but why is it shame? :)

Comment: @zur4ik Since that method wouldn't work in that case. Are you using the InnoDB engine or MyISAM engine?

Comment: I use `InnoDB` engine

Answer (score 1):

To delete just a row and it's direct children (not grandchildren):

```
DELETE FROM tablename where id = 1 or p_id = 1;
```

**UPDATE 1:**

If you have freedom to add a column to the table, you could add root_id and easily do the delete based on that. This will not ruin any current queries in your system and will only take a one-time run of a simple script to add the initial data.

```
DELETE FROM tablename where id = 1 or root_id = 1;
```

**UPDATE 2:**
A pretty awesome option is that foreign keys to the same table are allowed. So you can add a foreign key to p_id that references id, use `on delete cascade` and when you delete the root, all descendants will be removed also. I created a test table and this worked beautifully for me. It may also be beneficial to add `on update cascade`. Remember that p_id as well as id need to be unsigned for this to work.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD CONSTRAINT fk_tablename_id FOREIGN KEY (p_id) references tablename(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: In this case it will remove only 2 levels of menu. But what to do when I heve three levels?

Comment: Updated with a suggestion that will work if you have the freedom to add a column. Still trying to come up with a clever solution for the original table structure :P

Comment: Yes, this is another idea, but I will look forward for some kind of way, where structure will not be changed.

Comment: Here's a neat idea: foreign keys to the same table are valid. So you could set up `FOREIGN KEY p_id REFERENCES thistablesname(id) ON DELETE CASCADE` and then `DELETE FROM thistablesname where id = 1` would delete id 1 and all descendants.

Answer (score 1):

Just category id or parent id in first parameter:

```
function delete_parent_and_child_subchild($category_id,$all_cate=array())
        {
            if(!is_array($category_id))
            {           
                $this->db->where('parent_id', $category_id);
                $all_cate[]=$category_id;
            }
            else
            {           
                $this->db->where_in('parent_id', $category_id);
            }        
            $get_categories= $this->db->get('newcategory'); 

            if($get_categories->num_rows()>0)
            {
                $categories_vales=$get_categories->result(); 
                $new_subcat = array();
                foreach($categories_vales as $cate_val)
                {
                    $category_id=$cate_val->category_id;
                    array_push($new_subcat,$category_id);
                }
                $all_cate = array_merge($all_cate,$new_subcat);         
                if(count($new_subcat)>0)
                {
                    $this->delete_parent_and_child_subchild($new_subcat,$all_cate);
                }   

            }   
            $this->db->where_in('category_id', $all_cate)->delete('newcategory');
            return true;
        }
```